# Re-organizing branches in TFS, how to manage obsolete/orphan branches

Tags: tfs, version-control, branching-and-merging

The current branching method for the app I am working on is not at all structured. We are using TFS. I am planning to re-organize the branches. I looked up a some resources online and I have come-up with a plan. I want to check if this the correct way or if I should do things differently?

Following is the current branch hierarchy -

Main-branch
|-Release (Used once)
|
|-Dev-branch
     |-Dev (branch created but never used)
     |-***Development (Latest code)***
     |-Dev-guest-work (Used once and RI to Dev-branch)
     |-Test (Branch to release in test environment, no longer in use)
     |-UI-Dev-branch (no longer in use)

Following is my plan
1. Re-parent "Development" branch to "No parent"
2. Rename all other branches by prefixing "Obsolete". I don't want to delete them outright.
3. Rename "Development" to "Master" - this branch will have release ready code
4. Branch "Master" to create "Dev" branch
5. Use a "Hotfix" branch from "Master" if and when required

Please share any advice you have on this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to abandon all branches except Development?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to make the Development branch the main branch. And use a simple branch model. Remove all other branches since they are not being used. Thanks for your suggestion. I like what you suggested. I might go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider re-parent "Development" branch to "No parent", then perform a baseless merge to Main-branch, and re-parent Development to Main-branch. The the structure should look like:

```
|-Development
Main-branch
|-Release
```

You can continue develop in Development branch, if test pass, merge back to Main-branch. If you want to have a release, merge from Main-branch to Release branch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might go this way. A follow-up question. Do I need to make sure the development teams check-in all the files while I modify the branches? Or can they continue to work while I do these changes?

Comment: Just tested when a user is working on a branch, I reparented this branch, it didn't affect the user.